# How to save text input in kivy onto a variable

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner to kivy and I'm trying to make this app and the code is below wanted some help on how can I save the name of the person onto a variable so I can use it on other screens.
The custom screen class has my save name button and text input and I want to save the text input from this screen. when the user presses save name it changes screen to driving screen and wants to use that name in this screen
Please read it patiently and help me if you can.
Thank you

```
from kivy.app import App
import cv2
import numpy as np
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class CustomScreen(Screen):


    def softAlarm(self, *args):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('Soft-alarm-tone.mp3')
        self.sound.loop = True
        self.sound.play()



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(CustomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

 
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')


        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Driving Patner', font_size=50))


        navig = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.2)

        label1 = Label(text='Enter your name:', font_size = 30 , valign = 'bottom')

        navig.add_widget(label1)
      
        next = TextInput(font_size=30)

        name = next.text

        btn=Button(text='Save Name', font_size=30 , valign = 'bottom' ,halign='right')

        btn.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)
 
        navig.add_widget(next)
        navig.add_widget(btn)
        layout.add_widget(navig)


        self.add_widget(layout)


#Here we can write the code to start video analysis and all that
    def switch_next(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()



class DrivingScreen(Screen):



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(DrivingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)




        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')


        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Safe Driving', font_size=50))


        navig = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.2)

        next = Button(text='Start Driving')

        next.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)

        navig.add_widget(next)
        layout.add_widget(navig)

        self.add_widget(layout)

#Here we can write to stop video analysis 
    def switch_next(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') #reference: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades
        eyes = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml') #reference: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
        while (True):

                ret, frame = cap.read()

                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

                if len(faces) > 0:
                        print('Face Detected')
                else:
                        print('Face not Detected')
                #Clock.schedule_once(self.softAlarm, 3)
                #time.sleep(5) this freezes the whole program, best to find another way to implement
                #Event.wait(5)
                        cv2.rectangle(frame,(0,200), (640,300),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
                        cv2.putText(frame, "User Distracted",(150,265),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,2,(0,0,0),2 )
                #softAlarm()

                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                #getting coordinates of face
                #print(x,y,w,h)
                        roi = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

                #setting up bounding boxes for face
                        color = (0, 0, 255)                     #note that colors are in BGR and not RGB
                        color2 = (0, 255, 0 )
                        stroke = 3
                        width = x+w
                        height = y+h

                #drawing the bounding box with text
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (width, height), color, stroke )
                        cv2.putText(frame, "Face Detected", (x,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, color2, 2 )

                        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
     
                        eye = eyes.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=2)
                        if len(eye) > 0:
                                print('Eyes detected')
                        else:
                                print('Eyes not detected')
                                cv2.rectangle(frame,(0,200), (640,300),(0,0,255),cv2.FILLED)
                                cv2.putText(frame, "Pay Attention!",(150,265),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,2,(0,0,0),2 )
                        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eye:
                                cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh),color2,2)
                cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

class DrivingSummary(Screen):



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(DrivingSummary, self).__init__(**kwargs)




        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')


        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Here is your driving summary', font_size=50))


        navig = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.2)

        next = Button(text='START DRIVING AGAIN')

        next.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)

        navig.add_widget(next)
        layout.add_widget(navig)

        self.add_widget(layout)


    def switch_next(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()


class ScreenManagerApp(App):


    def build(self):

        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='Screen1'))
        root.add_widget(DrivingScreen(name='Screen2'))
        root.add_widget(DrivingSummary(name='Screen3'))
        return root


# This is only a protection, so that if the file
# is imported it won't try to launch another App

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # And run the App with its method 'run'
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a **minimal** working example of your program, less than *100* lines of code, for example, the `opencv` library is not needed at all to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You can save references to widgets that are in your `Screens`. For example, your name `TextInput` can be saved by modifying your `__init__()` method of `CustomScreen`:

```
    ...

    self.next = TextInput(font_size=30)  # save reference to this TextInput

    name = self.next.text

    btn = Button(text='Save Name', font_size=30, valign='bottom', halign='right')

    btn.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)

    navig.add_widget(self.next)

    ...
```

And in the `__init__()` method of `DrivingScreen`, you can create a `Label` to display the name:

```
    ...

    self.driver_name = Label(font_size=25)

    layout.add_widget(self.driver_name)

    ...
```

Then those references can be used in the `switch_next()` method of `CustomScreen`:

```
def switch_next(self, *args):
    self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
    self.manager.current = self.manager.next()
    self.manager.current_screen.driver_name.text = self.next.text
```